# Which is better, running Linux on Windows or vice versa

Tags: windows, ubuntu-core

am thinking about buying the newly launched Lenovo P50 machine. What will be better, installing Windows as host machine and running Linux inside a virtual machine or other way round??? What are the pros and cons of both approaches?

Comment: Obviously a question only you can answer. What you use most should be the main one.

Comment: Your host OS will run faster and have better control of the hardware than the virtual machine so it depends on what you intend to do with each OS.  To get the best out of both you can always dual boot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want less issues approach, I'd say Win-host Linux-virtual is the best for you. The biggest pro of Win-host Linux-virtual approach is drivers, in my opinion. With windows you hardly need to find drivers. With Linux, if you have Atheros or Broadcom wifi card, for instance, you may need proprietary drivers.  However, if you choose laptop wisely, with [Ubuntu-certified hardware](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/) , you should have no issues in that department. Second pro, would be avoiding issues with installation, especially with UEFI and Windows 8.1. There's lots of questions on askubuntu about that.

Otherwise, I don't see any more pros and cons. Eithern way you have a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to ask yourself which is your number one OS. That one should be you primary OS and then install the secondary within the primary.

You can also choose dual boot but then you have to reboot a lot if you want to change the OS and Windows cannot read/write linux partitions. Then you have two sets of important files. With one OS you can have all the files on the host server accessible also by the OS running as virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

How about duel booting? I have 2 computer that I run both on. I installed Windows 7 first then Ubuntu 14.04 and chose to duel boot using grub2. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

I have not tried it with Windows 8 or 10 but I have no reason to think it would not work.